# Writing larg BLOB throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: .net, mysql, entity-framework, ado.net, devart

I am having trouble writing large blobs to a MySQL-Database using the .net entity-framework.
Blobs < 1MB work fine. If I try to write a blob > 1MB a InvalidOperationException with text "Connection must be opened." occurs.

I am using:

1. Visual Studio 2010
2. .Net 3.5
3. Devart ADO.NET Entity Framework (latest)
4. MySSQl (latest)

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look to max_allowed_packet setting in mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql default packet size is 1MB this means that your query's result's data should fit in it. If you are trying to store multiple rows of information and if that is more then 1 MB the rows are split in transfer. But in case of large blob you can either increase your network packet size or store your information in smaller multiple rows as shown on this blog http://akashkava.com/blog/127/huge-file-storage-in-database-instead-of-file-system/

Comment: Increasing the value of the MySQL-Parameter max_allow_packet actually did the jobs.

Comment: Yes but that can cause more problems in bigger buffer being allocated and more memory consumption, so on high performance application this makes an impact.